# Return Confirm Call function if yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi would like to call a function if the answer to return confirm is yes, just don't know where to put the myFunction(). my code is below.

```
<a href="#" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like,

```
<a href="#" 
  onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?')){alert('Delete');} else {alert('Dont delete')}">
 Delete</a>
```

Snippet,

```html
    <a href="#" 
      onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?')){alert('Delete');} else {alert('Dont delete')}">
     Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to wire the method call with `&&`

```
<a href="#" onClick="confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?') && myFunction() ">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this .Don't use the confirmation inline of the  onlclick

1. Declare the `myfunction` in onclick
2. Then apply the confirmation inside the function

```js
function myfunction(){
if(confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?')){
//do stuff
console.log('yes')
}

}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="myfunction()">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?') && Yourfunction() "
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

`<a href="#" onClick="confirmDelete()">Delete</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete()
{
   if(confirm('Are you sure your want to delete?'))
   {
      /* Perform operations */
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myID").on("click",function(){
      if(confirm){
         alert('enter your code here');
      }
   });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myID">Delete</a>
```